# Closure Criterion for convergence of sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I know that $\{z\}=\bigcap\{\operatorname{cl}\,\{x_n\mid n\in S\} \mid S\subseteq \mathbb{N}\ \text{and}\ S\ \text{is infinite}\}$ is one of the criteria's of convergence of sequences in a metric space.

Here is my question :

> Can the intersection of the closures of the tails of a sequence be a singleton set without the sequence converging?

Comment: You are asking about "tails", so do you mean to ask whether a sequence $(x_n)$ converges if and only if there exists $z$ such that $\{z\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\mathrm{cl}\{x_n|n\geq k\}$? (This would hold in a compact space.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes i am asking about tails and yes the second part of your comment is exactly what i mean to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,\ldots)$$

Comment: @ Jonas Meyer Cool!.So, does the existence of such an example mean that this closure criterion is just a sufficient condition of convergence and not both necessary and sufficient ?

Comment: @johny: If the sequence converges, then the closure criterion holds, but not conversely in general.  Whether you use the word "sufficient" or "necessary" depends on which implication you are referring to, and I find your question confusing.  The closure criterion is necessary if the sequence converges, not sufficient to ensure that the sequence converges in general.

Comment: The closures of $\{x_n \mid n \in 2\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{x_n \mid n \in 2\mathbb{N} + 1\}$ are disjoint, are they not?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: That's true, but I thought tails were being asked about, a modified version of the criterion given at the beginning.  Thank you for asking, and I don't know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ah yes. I thought the question was asking about the converse of the initial statement, my bad.

Comment: @JonasMeyer One more thing, is the intersection of the closure of the tails of the sequence (1,0,2,0,3,0....) equal to {0} ?

Comment: @johny: Yes it is.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Alright,Thank you.